# Problem with installing the causalml library

Tags: python, pip, package, causalml

I am trying to install causalml package both using pip and from source following these instructions: https://causalml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Unfortunately I cannot succeed with building wheel for causalml: [ERROR:Failed building wheel for causalml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdRaj.png)

It looks like there is a problem with setup.py file which is part of repository I had to clone (according to the installation instructions).
I would be gratefull for any kind of ideas why I cannot install this package.

I've also installed Microsoft Visual C++ as it's suggested in error but it didn't change anything.
Your feedback and suggestion are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post an error message as text, not an image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I recomment [filing an issue](https://github.com/uber/causalml/issues/new/choose) with the maintainers of the package on GitHub.